# Partial derivative of a function with respect to product of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

If I have a function $f(x,y)$, and all I know about this function is its partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ as well as the position $(x_i, y_i)$ at which these partial derivatives were obtained, is it possible to obtain the partial derivative of $f(x,z)$ with respect to a new variable $z = x y$ while keeping $x$ constant, i.e. $\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial (z)}$ at the same point $(x_i, y_i)$, or $(x_i, x_i y_i)$?

Comment: Instead of “is it possible?”, the question you should ask yourself is what do you even **mean** by $\partial f/\partial (xy)$?

Comment: @HansLundmark I feel like I don't know what I don't know here. What is arbirary about that notation? In my example, $f$ could be expressed either as $f(x,y)$ or as $f(x,z)$ where $z = x \cdot y$. It can't feasibly be differentiated analytically, so the partial derivatives that I have are numerically derived and I'm interested in finding $\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}$ without calculating it separately in order to save computational time.

Comment: OK, if you say that you express $f$ as a function of $x$ and $z$, it becomes clear. The thing is that when you write $\partial f/\partial z$, it must be understood from context what *other* quantity that should be held constant as $z$ is varied. So in this case, it seems that you want to keep $x$ constant as $z$ varies. You could also imagine, for instance, introducing new variables $(w,z)=(x^2-y^2,xy)$ or something like that, and write $\partial f/\partial z$ to mean that $w$ is to be held constant as $z$ varies, and that would be something completely different!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thank you. Yes, I see now why I need to specify that I do indeed want to keep $x$ constant. I will amend the question above accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's be a bit careful with notation and write
$$
f(x,y) = g(x,xy)
,
$$
using different letters for the two functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,z)$. Then the derivative that you seek is $g_z(x,xy)$, that is, $\partial g/\partial z$ evaluated at the point $(x,z)=(x,xy)$. (I'll use subscripts to denote partial derivatives, since it's faster to type.)

The multivariable chain rule gives
$$
f_x(x,y) = g_x(x,y) + g_z(x,xy) \, y
,\qquad
f_y(x,y) = g_z(x,xy) \, x
,
$$
so the answer is simply (from the second of those two equations)
$$
g_z(x,xy) = \frac{f_y(x,y)}{x}
.
$$
(Which makes sense, since if you're holding $x$ fixed, varying $z=xy$ is basically the same thing as varying $y$; the only thing that differs is the scaling factor $x$.)